# Linking to SHARED Q_OBJECT: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const A::staticMetaObject"

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

I am trying to make two QObject libraries, using cmake on windows, where one depend on the other. If i build them both as STATIC libraries it works, but now that i need to build them as SHARED libraries, i keep getting compile errors.

- error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const A::staticMetaObject"

I am compiling using Visual Studio 19.

A small example of the problematic code:

First Library:

```
#include <QObject>
class A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(const QString& name){}
public Q_SLOTS:
    void ASlot(){}
};
```

Second Library

```
#include "A.hpp"
class B: public A {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    B():A("A"){}
private Q_SLOTS:
    void BSlot(){}
};
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Modules")

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_library(A SHARED A.hpp)
target_link_libraries(A ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(B SHARED B.hpp)
target_link_libraries(B A ${Qt5Core_LIBRARIES})
```

The code has been verified to work on linux, so i am guessing it might be a problem with how the dll symbols are exported. I have tried using the qt5_wrap_cpp() instead of automoc, but the result does not differ.

I hope someone can help me with the problem.

Comment: As library `B` uses `A`, then you need to **link** them: `target_link_libraries(B A)`.

Comment: Thanks i overlooked that, but it dosn't solve the problem

Comment: @KasperHøjLorenzen did you solved this issue? I have the same link error and I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: I took the lazy approach and just used them static

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if it is still relevant, but I solved the issue by following [this official Qt guide for creating shared libraries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html).

In your case, you should add the follwing lines before declaration of class A:

```
#if defined(A_EXPORT_SYMBOLS)
#  define A_DLL_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define A_DLL_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

then declare the class `A` in the following way:

```
class A_DLL_EXPORT A: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(const QString& name){}
public Q_SLOTS:
    void ASlot(){}
};
```

and then, add the compile definition to the target `A` in the cmake configuration:

```
add_compile_definitions(A PRIVATE A_EXPORT_SYMBOLS)
```

note that the definition must be PRIVATE in order to have a `Q_DECL_EXPORT` declaration only in your A dll.

The same goes for class B.

Comment: I'll check the solution one of the coming days